# python 2.7 Prototyping/forward reference

Tags: python

I want to do something like this in Python.  I took out what we are really doing and replaced it with this ridiculous example that will really never end.  Please assume the calls from a<==>b are finite.  Our code does have the logic to end the cycle.

I am worried that I will get an error for calling b in a before b is defined.  However, I read that as long as I don't make a call that executes a before def b then I should have no problem.  What is the real answer here?  And what is python doing behind the scenes to make it not exit on line 2 (b())

```
def a():
    b()

def b():
    a()

b()
```

Comment: Why don't you just try this out? If you really don't want the hassle of dealing with this on your local machine, try it on http://ideone.com.

Comment: I did test it out.  I apparently forgot to add the part about why does it work.  I edited it.

Comment: @Jake: I don't get the last sentence of your edit. Why would the script exit at line 2?

Comment: b() doesn't exist yet.  Why doesn't python throw a bit about use of an undefined function?  Your answer is wonderful and explains it, but is it unreasonable that I expected that behavior?

Comment: Also, to the vote down, any reason?  I am fairly sure this isn't a copy.  To someone who doesn't know the guts of python the answer to this question could be helpful. c users for instance might be expecting the ability to prototype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real answer is that `b` inside the definition of `a` will be looked up in the module scope and similarly for `a` inside the definition of `b`. Since `a` and `b` both exist in the module scope after both definitions have been processed, your mutual recursion will work.

(It will stop working if the names `a` and `b` are shadowed inside the function definitions, but I assume you'll manage to avoid that.)

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) for an overview of Python scoping rules.

Answer (score 1):

This will work fine, upto a recursion depth of 1000 calls. It depends on what you're using it for as to whether this is an issue or not.

Check doing a search on recursive functions to find out more...

Comment: Answer is factual.  To the question of "does it work" it answers yes.

Comment: @Marcin - It is an answer, the question asks if the code will work, I reply saying yes, upto 1000 calls.